# I'm trying to draw shapes in a JPanel extending a JComponent and then putting the component inside the panel but it won't work

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, jcomponent

I'm trying to draw shapes in a JPanel extending a JComponent and then putting the component inside the panel but it won't work. I've got a JFrame (500, 500) and I need the right half of it to have things drown inside. I'm clearly doing something wrong though!
This is the code I've used:

```
public class Componente extends JComponent{
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        Shape linea = new Rectangle2D.Float(50, 50, 50, 50);
        Shape cerchio = new Ellipse2D.Double(100, 100, 50, 50);


        g2.setPaint(Color.BLUE);

        g2.draw(linea);
        g2.draw(cerchio);
    }
}


    public class PannelloDx extends JPanel{
    PannelloDx(){
        this.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        this.setSize(Esercitazione_Berni1703.finestra.getWidth()/2, Esercitazione_Berni1703.finestra.getHeight());
        this.setLocation(Esercitazione_Berni1703.finestra.getWidth()/2, 0);
        this.add(new Componente());
    }
}
```

Now, the output shows the Cyan panel into the JFrame in the right half as it's supposed to. It won't show anything though!

Comment: Start replying / accepting answers in older questions before asking new questions.

Answer (score 1):

By default a JPanel uses a FlowLayout and a FlowLayout respects the size of the component added to it. Your custom component has a preferred size of (0, 0) so there is nothing to paint.

You need to override the `getPreferredSize()` method of your custom panel to return the appropriate size.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and examples. Check out the rest of the tutorial for Swing basics as well.